# Replacing characters in string without replace() function

Tags: python, string, list, replace

This is mostly a logic problem. I am trying to replace a character in a string without using the replace function. I am trying to first change it into a list, change the elements, then turn it back into string. My attept:

```
def changeCar(ch,ca1,ca2):
    a=list(ch)
    for x in a:
        if x==ca1:
             x==ca2
    return a
```

However this doesn't work. Besides, I am not sure how to transform it back into a string.

Comment: How doesn't it work? What do you expect and what actually occurs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to define a string as a list in python.

```
string = 'The quick brown fox jusmps over the lazy dog'
# Define your variables
result = ''
for i in string:
        if i == 'o':
                i = '0'
        result += i
print result
```

If you MUST however use a list:

```
string = list('The quick brown fox jusmps over the lazy dog')
result = []
for i in string:
        if i == 'o':
                i = '0'
        result.append(i)
print ''.join(result)
```

Comment: The list approach is preferable to concatenating strings in a loop (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133571/most-pythonic-way-to-concatenate-strings)).

Comment: Thank you! I don't actually have to use lists, I just thought it would be sensible. But yes, leaving it a string is neater. :)

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. Since Python strings are immutable, you aren't able to change the characters in place, so the approach of spliting it into a list of characters, modifying the elements inside that list, and then re-joining it is correct. Your solution isn't working because `x` isn't a reference (or **pointer**) to the elements inside the list, but a copy of them. Thus, `x = c2` (and not `x == c2`, as your example shows) only modifies the copy. You'll have to access the list by index, like so:

```
for ind in range(len(a)):
    if a[ind] == ca1:
         a[ind] = ca2

return "".join(a)
```

You can also use a list comprehension for maximum brevity, though it *might* be a little unreadable:

```
return "".join([(char if char != ca1 else ca2) for char in ch])
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't change the string into a list. That's unnecessary. Instead, define an empty string in the function definition and then append to it accordingly and in the end return the value of that variable:

```
def changeCar(ch,ca1,ca2):
    b = ''
    for x in ch:
        if x!= ca1:
            b+= x
        else:
            b+=ca2
    return b
```

Now you get:

```
>>> changeCar("abc","b","c")
'acc'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

`a == b` is a [Comparison Expression](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/expressions.html#not-in).  `a = b` is an [Assignment Statement](https://docs.python.org/2.7/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements).  To turn a list into a string:

```
>>> ''.join(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'])
'abcdefg'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

For simple manipulations like this you can use list comprehensions.
Try it like this:

```
In [1]: text = "Hello, World!"
In [2]: ''.join([ch if ch != 'o' else 'a' for ch in text])
Out[2]: 'Hella, Warld!'
```

This list comprehension replaces the character 'o' with 'a'