# How to insert a variable value in a string in python

Tags: python, string, input

Here is a simple example

```
amount1 = input("Insert your value: ")
amount2 = input("Insert your value: ")
print "Your first value is", amount1, "your second value is", amount2
```

This is ok, but I would like to know if there is another method to include the variable in the string without concatenation or a comma.

Is this possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Most Pythonic way to concatenate strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133571/most-pythonic-way-to-concatenate-strings)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With Python 3.6+ ([PEP498](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)), you can use formatted string literals, also known as f-strings:

```
amount1 = input('Insert your value: ')
amount2 = input('Insert your value: ')

print(f'Your first value is {amount1}, your second value is {amount2}')
```

Answer (score 18):

Use string formatting:

```
s = "Your first value is {} your second value is {}".format(amount1, amount2)
```

This will automatically handle the data type conversion, so there is no need for `str()`.

Consult the Python docs for detailed information:

https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/string.html#formatstrings

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53865969/3052535 is better to read and shorter.

Comment: @Manuel It requires 3.6+, and is not necessarily easier to read in complex cases. This way you can also do: `"{arg1}".format(arg1=my_var)` btw

Comment: Didn't know the 3.6 restriction. Cool thanks! Giving the argument name is very nice.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use the old kind of % formatting:

```
print "this is a test %03d which goes on" % 10
```

This page https://pyformat.info/ has quite a nice comparison !