# Python .format() not yielding desired output

Tags: python-3.x

This is my code:

```
form.format(**values).replace('None', 'null')
```

This is my form and values which i am passing in the code:

```
values = {'id': 16, 'name': 'PlayStation 3 OS', 'last_modified': '2018-08-16 13:25:46'}
form = %s,%s,%s
```

When i print my code.My code outputs this:

```
%s,%s,%s
```

what is the error?

Comment: .`format()` does not recognize `%s` or any other `%` placeholder. You should use `{}`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to insert a variable value in a string in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44462209/how-to-insert-a-variable-value-in-a-string-in-python)

Comment: @DYZ it is still showing same.Please check in your compiler and help me sir.I did this

Comment: print('{},{},{}'.format(**values).replace('None', 'null'),'ccc')
IndexError: Replacement index 0 out of range for positional args tuple

Comment: `.format()` does not work with dictionaries, either. You mixed up several incompatible formatting methods.

Answer (score 0):

use
`form='{} {} {}'`
instead of %s

`values = {'id': 16, 'name': 'PlayStation 3 OS', 'last_modified': '2018-08-16 13:25:46'}`

`form = "{} {} {}"`

`print(form.format(values['id'],values['name'],values['last_modified']))`

Comment: it shows     print('{},{},{}'.format(**values).replace('None', 'null'),'ccc')
IndexError: Replacement index 0 out of range for positional args tuple

Comment: once try the code after adding ---replace('None', 'null')

Comment: i tried it's not working you can check in onliner interpreter sir.PLease help me.

Comment: can u briefly tell what u are trying to achieve in this piece of code??
u want to print the values in the dictionary with proper formatting ?

Comment: print("{:s},{:s},{:s}.".format(*values))

once try this
with ur code